# R Error: Expecting a single string value: [type=character; extent=5]

Tags: r, function, search, optimization, tree

I am working with the R programming language. I am using the "CORELS" library in R, here is an example (CORELS is a statistical model that is similar to a decision tree):

```
library(corels)

logdir <- tempdir()
rules_file <- system.file("sample_data", "compas_train.out", package="corels")
labels_file <- system.file("sample_data", "compas_train.label", package="corels")
meta_file <- system.file("sample_data", "compas_train.minor", package="corels")

stopifnot(file.exists(rules_file),
          file.exists(labels_file),
          file.exists(meta_file),
          dir.exists(logdir))

corels(rules_file, labels_file, logdir, meta_file,
       verbosity_policy = "silent",
       regularization = 0.015,
       curiosity_policy = 2,   # by lower bound
       map_type = 1)       # permutation map
cat("See ", logdir, " for result file.")
```

The output can be viewed here:

```
OPTIMAL RULE LIST
if ({sex:Male,juvenile-crimes:>0}) then ({recidivate-within-two-years:Yes})
else if ({priors:>3}) then ({recidivate-within-two-years:Yes})
else ({recidivate-within-two-years:No})
```

**My Question:** I am still a bit confused as to how the syntax works for the above functions. For example, I am trying to use the above functions on the "iris" dataset:

```
data(iris)
head(iris)

  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

Now, I tried to apply the "corles" function on the iris data set:

```
logdir <- tempdir()
rules_file <- iris
labels_file <- colnames(iris)

corels(rules_file, labels_file, logdir, 
       verbosity_policy = "silent",
       regularization = 0.015,
       curiosity_policy = 2,   # by lower bound
       map_type = 1)       # permutation map
cat("See ", logdir, " for result file.")
```

But this produces the following error:

```
Error in corels(rules_file, labels_file, logdir, verbosity_policy = "silent",  : 
  Expecting a single string value: [type=character; extent=5].
```

Can someone please show me how to fix this error?

Thanks

References:

- https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/corels/versions/0.0.2/topics/corels
- https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/corels/index.html

Comment: I had a similar (confusing) error. Here's how to parse the error itself. Obviously, it was expecting a string. But, then it lists what you gave it instead an array of extent 5 (which means 5 elements) and each element is of type character.

Comment: First, I was confused because I thought it was ASKING FOR a string, type_character with extent=5 and assumed it meant a string of 5 characters. Only when I realized the 5 (in my case, it was 2) was the number of elements did I realize it the part in brackets described the array I erroneously gave it and definitely not the string that it wants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to pass datasets to the `corels()` function, however it wants you to pass *file names*. The [Data Format](https://github.com/corels/corels#data-format) section of the github for the `corels` software has details on how to format your data structures. These should then be saved in files and then passed to `corels()`.

Each row in the data file should contain a rule name surrounded by curly braces, `{` and `}`, followed by a `0` or `1` to indicate whether that rule is true for that given row of data.

Here's a simple script to construct some:

```
library(corels)

# Write a function to take a dataset & expression and format it correctly
make_rule <- function(data,expr){
  rule_name <- deparse1(substitute(expr))
  rule_name <- gsub(" ","",rule_name)
  out <- eval(substitute(expr),data)
  paste0("{",rule_name,"} ",paste0(1*out,collapse=" "))
}

# Create names for our rule/label files

rules_file <- "rule_data"
labels_file <- "label_data"

# Create some example rules (must always be binary operations)
iris_rules <- c(
  make_rule(iris,Sepal.Length < 5.84),
  make_rule(iris,Sepal.Width < 3.05),
  make_rule(iris,Petal.Length < 3.76),
  make_rule(iris,Petal.Width < 1.2)
)

#Label data appropriately. Must be a pair of rules
# where the first is the negative option & the 2nd is the
# positive outcome. Here we want to know how to find when
# the flower is a setosa
iris_labels <- c(
  make_rule(iris,Species != "setosa"),
  make_rule(iris,Species == "setosa")
)

# Save the data in the files
writeLines(iris_rules,rules_file)
writeLines(iris_labels,labels_file)


# reference the files and set verbosity to high so
# we get the full output
corels(rules_file, labels_file, ".",
       verbosity_policy = "loud")
```

Comment: @ Michael Barrowman: thank you for your reply! two questions

Comment: 1) why is this step necessary? iris_rules <- c(
  make_rule(iris,Sepal.Length < 5.84),
  make_rule(iris,Sepal.Width < 3.05),
  make_rule(iris,Petal.Length < 3.76),
  make_rule(iris,Petal.Width < 1.2)
) ... are you sure we can just define random rules?

Comment: 2) can this library only be used for binary classification? it can not handle multiclass outputs? Or does it only handle binary classification? E.g. iris_labels <- c(
  make_rule(iris,Species != "setosa"),
  make_rule(iris,Species == "setosa")
)

Comment: 1) This s necessary because it needs to be in that format. The `make_rule()` function handles this. This function allows for any definition of rules, provided the output is logical.
2) I cannot answer this in regards to multi-class labels, you would have to read the documentation that I linked to to understand the capabilities of the `corels` software. From my understanding however, if this is possible, you would have to define label for each category (e.g. `c(make_rule(iris,Species=="setosa"),make_rule(iris,Species=="versicolor"),make_rule(iris,Species=="virginica"))`

Comment: thank you for your reply! Why did you only decide to define 4 rules? was there any reason that they were defined in this format?

Comment: I did 4 rules because there are 4 predictor variables in the iris dataset. You can do however many you want, but they have to be binary rules